# RegisterPage.html:57 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined ( IONIC 4)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

This error is occurring when trying to access a registration page...
The error is generated when the login page I try to access the page to register
Error:

```
RegisterPage.html:57 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
```

my register.component.html

```js
    <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (submit)="register()">
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item class="boder-input">
          <ion-label position="floating">
            <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon> Nome
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item class="boder-input">
          <ion-label position="floating">
            <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon> Email
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item class="boder-input">
          <ion-label position="floating">
            <ion-icon name="logo-github"></ion-icon> Git
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" formControlName="git"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item class="boder-input">
          <ion-label position="floating">
            <ion-icon name="key"></ion-icon> Senha
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item class="boder-input">
          <ion-label position="floating">
            <ion-icon name="key"></ion-icon> Confirmar senha
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="password" formControlName="pass"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button type="submit" color="primary" [disabled]="!form.valid" expand="block">Cadastrar</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </form>
```

My register.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { resolve } from 'url';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {

  registerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuild: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuild.group({
      email: [' ', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: [' ', Validators.required],
      pass: [' ', Validators.required],
      name: [' ', Validators.required],
      git: [' ', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  register() {
    const nome = this.registerForm.get('name').value;
    const email = this.registerForm.get('email').value;
    const password = this.registerForm.get('password').value;
    const confPass = this.registerForm.get('pass').value;
    const git = this.registerForm.get('git').value;
    const gitData = this.getDev(git);
    gitData.then(dados => {
      this.authService.register(nome, email, password, confPass, git,
        dados.html_url, dados.avatar_url, dados.followers, dados.following).subscribe(
          (data: any) => {
            return this.router.navigate(['']);
          },
          erro => {
            this.handleError(erro);
          }
        );

    });
  }

  async getDev(git: string) {
    const url = 'https://api.github.com/users/' + git;
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const json = await resp.json();
    return json;
  }

  handleError(erro) {

  }
}
```

My register.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {  ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { RegisterPage } from './register.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RegisterPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [RegisterPage]
})
export class RegisterPageModule {}
```

It seems to me that is not being able to read the formsControll the html. Has anyone been through this same situation?
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `form` to `registerForm`

```
<ion-button type="submit" color="primary" [disabled]="!registerForm.valid" expand="block">Cadastrar</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

inside your my register.component.html u need to change your form name group to **registerForm** from **form** inside ur button [disabled] tag

```
    <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (submit)="register()">
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item class="boder-input">
          <ion-label position="floating">
            <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon> Nome
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item class="boder-input">
          <ion-label position="floating">
            <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon> Email
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item class="boder-input">
          <ion-label position="floating">
            <ion-icon name="logo-github"></ion-icon> Git
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" formControlName="git"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item class="boder-input">
          <ion-label position="floating">
            <ion-icon name="key"></ion-icon> Senha
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item class="boder-input">
          <ion-label position="floating">
            <ion-icon name="key"></ion-icon> Confirmar senha
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="password" formControlName="pass"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button type="submit" color="primary" [disabled]="!registerForm.valid" expand="block">Cadastrar</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </form>
```